# Magento admin page taking forever to load

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, backend, magento-2.3

[image]I have installed Magento 2.3.3 , the frontend is showing properly but when the admin page is taking forever to load . The cursor keeps rolling and it won't load so that I can click the panels on the admin page , I am attempting to run it on Windows . What could be wrong ?

Comment: How we can help you? we doesn't known anything of your project.... we can't see any error or code son we can't help you. I'll suggest to se browser console if the loading system requires ajax.

Comment: SSH to your Magento root dir and type `php bin/magento cache:status` ... see which are enabled. Also check `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show` - if you're in *developer* mode, it'll likely be slow. Is this a *live* or *dev* environment? If it is a development environment, what OS are you running?

Comment: ... are you attempting to run this on Windows?

Comment: @CD001 Yes I am attempting to run it on Windows .

Comment: @Sfili_81 I have attached a picture of the error details in browser console

Comment: M2 doesn't play well with Windows (as of version 2.2.8 IIRC); it [doesn't validate filepaths](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256223/how-to-install-magento-2-3-on-windows-10-x64-with-sample-data/256238) so you either need to hack the core code or run it on *nix - setting up Debian on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is reasonably painless. Alternatively, []this guide](https://www.navisiontech.com/installing-magento-2-3-0-on-a-local-windows-host/) seems like it should work for running on Windows.

Comment: @CD001 Thanks much , the instruction on the posted link worked , just that I keep getting "One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Page Cache. Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types." error , but that doesn't seem to be much of an issue so I will work on it . Thanks much once again , you're a life saver !

Comment: No worries ;) If it's a dev box you can just disable the page cache (it'll only get in the way when you're changing things) - you'll only realistically be able to use a file-based FPC anyway, getting Redis or Varnish to work on a Windows dev environment really doesn't seem worth the effort.